# How to convert a Json to Graphql mutation format

Tags: json, graphql

I have a Json object and I want to convert it graphql mutation query inorder to invoke a graphql api. So my requirement is I need to create a springboot project and expose a POST API which will take input as a json and convert it into graphql mutation query format, then I need to consume a graphql api with the mutation query. Can any one please provide any pointer to it as I am not able to proceed.